# How to increase the movement speed of enemy based on score?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get the enemy movement speed go faster than it was before the certain scored points. I am  a novice programmer so if the code seems ugly please bear with it. If anyone could help me get through with this it would be really awesome. Thank You.

Here is my Score Managing code:

```
public class ScoreManager : MonoBehaviour 
{
     public float score;
     public float pointsPerSecond;
     public float highScore;

     public bool scoreIncreasing;

     public Text scoreText;

     void Start()
     {
         score = 0;

         if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("HighScore")) // checks if player has HighScore or not
         {
             highScore = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("HighScore"); //gets the value of stored highscore.
         }
     }

     void Update()
     {        
         if (scoreIncreasing) //checks if score is increasing or not
         {
             score += pointsPerSecond * Time.deltaTime; //increases score as per time
         }

         if (score > highScore) // checks if score is greater than highscore or not
         {
             highScore = score; //sets value of score to highscore
             PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("HighScore", highScore); // stores the value of highscore
         }
         scoreText.text = ((int)score).ToString() + " Clicks"; 
         //provieds the value of score to score text object.
     }    
}
```

and here is my enemy mover code:

```
public class EnemyMover : MonoBehaviour
{    
     [SerializeField]
     private float tumble;

     public float baseSpeed = 2f;
     public float newSpeed;
     public float multiplier;

     public float scoreToNextLevel = 10f;

     void Start ()
     {
         GetComponent<Rigidbody>().angularVelocity = Random.insideUnitSphere * tumble; //makes the object rotate
         FindObjectOfType<ScoreManager>(); //caches the scoremanaging script
         baseSpeed *= multiplier; //gives basespeed a value eg baseSpeed(2) * multiplier(2) = 4.
     }

     void Update ()
     {
         GoUp(); //calls method goup
         EnemyMovement(); //calls method enemy movement
     }

     public void EnemyMovement()
     {
         if(FindObjectOfType<ScoreManager>().score > scoreToNextLevel)    
         //checks whether the condition is true
         {
             NewSpeed();  //calls method newspeed
             SpeedUp();    // calls method speedup
         }
         multiplier += 1;  // increases the value of multiplier by 1
     }

     public void GoUp()
     {
         transform.position += Vector3.up * baseSpeed * Time.deltaTime;  //moves the enemy object upwards in y axis.
     }

     public void NewSpeed()
     {
         newSpeed = baseSpeed * multiplier * Time.deltaTime; // proves new speed with a value.     
     }

     public void SpeedUp()
     {
         transform.position += Vector3.up * newSpeed; // moves enemy object upwards into y axis using new speed.   
     }
}
```

Comment: Pass the `score` value to the Enemy, then just do calculations inside one of your speed methods.

Comment: I did that but my multiplier gets added infinitely which causes my enemy to move way faster than i can see.

Comment: Unrelated tip: note the description of the [tag:visual-studio] tag: *Use this tag if you have a specific question about Visual Studio features and functionality. DO NOT use this tag on questions regarding code which merely happened to be written in Visual Studio.* So it doesn't apply to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, i figured it out. I did it like this.

```
void Update ()
{
    if (FindObjectOfType<ScoreManager>().score > scoreToNextLevel) // checks if score 
is greater than score to next level, if yes then following codes are applied.
    {            
        multiplier += 1f; // increases the value of multiplier by 1.
        baseSpeed += multiplier;// adds the multiplier value to basespeed.
        EnemyMovement();//calls the enemymovement method
        scoreToNextLevel *= 2;// multiplies the score to next level by 2.
    }
```

Comment: Just a general Unity tip, don't use the FindObjectOfType inside code that'll be executed every frame, all of the Find methods have poor performance. Set the ScoreManager as a SerializeField in your class. I'd also question whether you need to check the difference between two numbers in Update - can't you just create an event to do this check after the score has been increased?

Comment: Thank You, @Steven Coull for that tip, really appreciated that. I am really new to this unity and programming, what event do i create to check for the difference in two numbers?

Comment: Any generic method for your class. `public void ChangeSpeed(float newSpeed) { currentSpeed = newSpeed;}`